# What is the difference between identifying using @ and without it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to **C#** programming and was reading in C Sharp 2010 for programmers and this interrupted me.

> Identifiers
>   may also be preceded by the @ character. This indicates that a word should be interpreted
>   as an identifier, even if it’s a keyword (e.g., @int). This allows C# code to use code written
>   in other .NET languages where an identifier might have the same name as a C# keyword.

1-Can anyone explain what will the interrupter do if a @character was used with an example please, and how it is different than identifying without the @character.

2- how can it be used in other .NET languages

Comment: You've posted the answer yourself (the block quote). What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @stakx, i said with an example , secondly how to use other ,net codes in C#

Comment: Your block quote contains an example: _"… that a word should be interpreted as an identifier, even if it is a keyword (e.g., @int)."_ Regarding how the same is done in other .NET languages; which ones are you interested in? VB.NET? F#? IL? Boo? Nemerle? IronPython? IronScheme? ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` character allows you to use reserved keywords as identifier names:

```
int @int = 1;
```

Or

```
void M(object[] @params) 
{ }
```

Without it, the compiler would emit an error ([CS1041](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47dbdc1k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) that you are attempting to use a keyword as an identifier name:

> Identifier expected, *'keyword'* is a keyword.
>   A reserved word for the C# language was found where an identifier was expected. Replace the *keyword* with a user-specified identifier.

A list of reserved keywords can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).

Comment: can you please explain how can i use @ character in other .NET langauges

Comment: yes ,the author said that C# code can use other .net languages codes . so how can i benefit of this

Comment: What the author ment is that you can leverage this with other .NET languages where C# keywords are totally valid identifier names. For example, if an F# library uses `params` as an identifier name, you could bypass it by adding the `@` character to that variable.